# How to unprotect one route in firebase functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, firebase-authentication

I used this code sample [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js), in which a snippet is attached:

```
const validateFirebaseIdToken = (req, res, next) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {});
  // console.log("Check if request is authorized with Firebase ID token");

  if (
    (!req.headers.authorization ||
      !req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer ")) &&
    !(req.cookies && req.cookies.__session)
  ) {
    console.error(
      "No Firebase ID token was passed as a Bearer token in the Authorization header.",
      "Make sure you authorize your request by providing the following HTTP header:",
      "Authorization: Bearer <Firebase ID Token>",
      'or by passing a "__session" cookie.'
    );
    res.status(403).send("Unauthorized");
    return;
  }

  let idToken;
  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer ")
  ) {
    console.log('Found "Authorization" header');
    // Read the ID Token from the Authorization header.
    idToken = req.headers.authorization.split("Bearer ")[1];
  } else if (req.cookies) {
    console.log('Found "__session" cookie');
    // Read the ID Token from cookie.
    idToken = req.cookies.__session;
  } else {
    // No cookie
    res.status(403).send("Unauthorized");
    return;
  }
```

My question is, after including this in my index.js file for my firebase functions, *all* of my routes are protected. I have a `GET` route that I do not need protected, and in fact, makes it more complicated when I protect the route. How can I avoid protecting this route:

```
app.post("/getArt", (req, res) => {
  admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("art")
    .where("date", "==", req.body.day)
    .limit(1)
    .get()
    .then((data) => {
      let arr = [];
      data.forEach((doc) => {
        arr.push(doc.data());
      });
      return res.json(arr);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
});
```

I have several other endpoints in the file that I want to stay protected via Authorization tokens, but this one route does not need to be protected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you're showing here is only showing the definition of `validateFirebaseIdToken`, but not where it's being used.  In the linked example, you can see it's being applied to the entire app:

```
app.use(validateFirebaseIdToken);
```

If you do this, it will apply to **all** of your routes - that's the way middleware works at the [application level](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.application).

If you want this middleware to apply to only certain routes, you should pass it as an argument to `app.post()` as shown in the documentation for [router-level middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router).  You will want to pass the middleware function to `app.post()` so that it describes all of the processing to be done for that route.

```
app.post("/routeYouWantProtected", validateFirebaseIdToken, (req, res) => { ... })
```

Alternatively, you could rewrite the middleware to only decode the token if it was provided.  If you do that, you can check inside your handler function if it was, and decide what to do with that outcome.